# print n number in specific format

Tags: java, loops

I want to print n number in this format :

```
 5    
 5 4
 5 4 3
 5 4 3 2
 5 4 3 2 1
```

but when I tried to print using is code, 
I got only

```
5
5 4
5 4 3
5 4 3 2
```

I didn't get

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code.

```
 for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=n; j>n-i ;j--){
    System.out.print(j);
       }
     System.out.println();
          }
```

Comment: change it to: `for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop for j can represent the x axis, and the i can represent the y axis. When you input n, it should be one more for the y axis because you are missing the last step. So it should be changed to

```
for(int i=1; i <=n; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `i<=n`, that will include the last n as well.